# Different type of import AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, import

I'm an Angular beginner, I'm trying to understand the difference between import something in a controller, for example $http, in [] and like parameter in function.

In other words, what is the difference between something like this

```
.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    ...
});
```

and this

```
.controller('customersCtrl',['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
   ...
}]);
```

I checked out documentation and a lot of examples about it but I don't understand.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my basic question.

Regards

Comment: there is no difference between them in terms of functionality except while minification the latter is used for proper injection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both do the same thing. But the second method is safer for minification.

If you would minify:

```
.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  ...
});
```

It would break because $scope and $http would be renamed to a and b.

You can read more about it here:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/declaring-angularjs-modules-for-minification

As stated in the linked article you can also inject it in the controller using:

```
mainController.$inject = ['$scope'];
```

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di - reading the documentation for dependency injection in angular should be enough. More or less it's like what yeouuu said.

When everything is minified and uglified you receive i.e. function(paramOne, paramTwo) -> function(a,b). On runtime you cannot find our which search you actually included. Strings are not minified. So basically on runtime you have mapping between  controller('AnyCtrl,['$scope','$http', function(a,b){}]); 
It knows that a corresponds to be $scope and b corresponds to $http. That's the reason why the order matters as well.